# toolsVersion="11201" is messing my storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

After updating my xCode to 8.0 and run my application on my device, i've noticed that my collection view in the storyboard is messed and the frame isn't fitting the view anymore.

This is happening only if i opened the storyboard(It seems that the xcode is adding some properties after the first time I opened the file in xcode).
When I replace the storyboard with my old one then build the app without opening it everything worked as expected.

After hours of searching what may be the reason and comparing the storyboards source codes (between the old one and the new one after opening it), I have found that the reason is the toolsVersion property found at the top of the storyboard source code.

```
     <document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" 
     toolsVersion="11201" systemVersion="15G1004" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"
     propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" colorMatched="YES"
     initialViewController="wZn-Em-z41">
```

When I replace `toolsVersion="11201" with toolsVersion="10116"` then everything works again normally.

How can I force the tools version to a value? and what is this property and why it is messing up my constraints and frames.

Appreciate any information about this issue.

Comment: I have the exact same problem...and after hours of investigation I came to the exact same conclusion about the toolsVersion (10116 works fine, 11201 screws up one of my table views). Seems to be an Xcode 8 bug :(

Comment: So I determined my issue...I'm setting my table view's bottom contentInset based on the height of an image view. For some reason, Xcode 8 toolsVersion (11201) is causing that image view to report it's size as 1000 x 1000. I need to get to the bottom of why the image view is having a problem, but that's why my UITableView had way too much "content." Could your problem be similar?

Comment: It seems that the new Xcode 8 toolsVersion (11201) removes a lot of <rect key="frame" ... /> references from the storyboard (seems to be for views that have constraints on them). So, if you rely on the frame for anything in your code, since it isn't there in the storyboard anymore, the frame seems to be reported as 1000 x 1000 until constraints have had a chance to be evaluated. Does this make sense in your case? Are you relying on the frame of something that uses constraints before the constraints have been evaluated? (i.e. in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear, they have not been evaluated yet)

Comment: @EthanG exactly, thank you for the clarification above. This was exactly what i was facing. I solved this by putting everything in the viewDidLoad method inside performSelectorAfterDelay:0 .. Maybe that allowed the constraints to be evaluated. Stupid Xcode 8 Update!.. thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that, with toolsVersion 11201 (Xcode 8), it seems that views that have fully qualified constraints no longer have frames specified in the storyboard (since the constraints will determine the frame at runtime).

So you can't rely on the frame until the constraints have been evaluated (i.e. don't use frames in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear). Once the constraints have been evaluated, the frame seems to be fine. Before they have been evaluated, the frame seems to be reported as 1000 x 1000 (at least, that's what it was for me in various cases).

So there are two solutions: 1) Make an outlet to your constraints and use that instead of relying on the frame, or 2) use the frame *after* the constraints have been evaluated (for example, in the viewDidAppear method).

Comment: or use `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`, noting that it could get called multiple times